# InstallShield wont accept <

Tags: visual-studio, installshield

As per these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019%5D%5B1%5D

I am trying to create a setup file. I create the PRQ file but when I press Refresh in VisualStuido Install shield project I get this error:

```
"The character < cannot be used in an attribute value"
```

the .PRQ file is not accepted by InstallShield.
It seems the offending character is in this line:

```
...
LocalFile="<ISProductFolder>
...
```

because when i remove this attribute InstallShield accepts the PRQ file.
The funny thing is that as per InstallShield docs this attribute (angle brackets and all) is valid:

https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/PrereqBuildLocation.htm

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I opened another PRQ file and found out how an attribute must be specified. It should be like this:

```
&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;
```

NOT like this:

```
<ISProductFolder>
```